# Hibernate 4.3.0 final and spring 4.1

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$29.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:875)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$29.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:864)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
    ... 86 more
```

Geting the above exception.

Following is class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Number userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = true)
    private String userName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_ID", unique=false, nullable=true, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private Client client;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = true)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD_CREATION_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp passwordCreationDate;

    @Column(name = "SALT", nullable = true)
    private String salt;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Number addressId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = true)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = true)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL" , nullable = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "IS_MADE_UP_USER_NAME"  , nullable = true)
    private boolean isMadeUpUserName;

    @Column(name = "CELL_PHONE" , nullable = true)
    private Number cellPhone;

    @Column(name = "LAST4SSN"  , nullable = true)
    private String last4SSN;

    @Column(name = "LOCKED" , nullable = false)
    private boolean locked;

    @Column(name = "FAILED_LOGIN_COUNT" , nullable = true)
    private Integer failedLoginCount;

    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATED" , nullable = false)
    private Timestamp dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "DATE_MODIFIED" , nullable = true)
    private Timestamp dateModified;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY_ID" , nullable = true)
    private Number createdBy;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY_ID" , nullable = true)
    private Number modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "TIME_ZONE" , nullable = true)
    private String timeZone;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE"  , nullable = true)
    private String language;

    @Column(name = "USER_ENTERED_TEL"  , nullable = true)
    private Number userEnteredTel;

    @Column(name = "DO_NOT_NOTIFY"  , nullable = true)
    private boolean doNotNotify;
    enter code here
    @Column(name = "DISABLED"  , nullable = true)
    private boolean disabled;

    @Column(name = "TERMS_CONFIRMED" , nullable = true)
    private boolean termsConfirmed;
```

I don't know were am i wrong,please help me to solve the above.
getting deserialization exception.Due to this desialixation its causing eof exception too.the error in the above class.

following is table structure

```sql
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_id` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_made_up_user_name` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cell_phone` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last4ssn` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `failed_login_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` date NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_id` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by_id` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_entered_tel` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `do_not_notify` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `terms_confirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `USERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`)
                            REFERENCES `client` (`client_id`)
```

Comment: When exactly does that exception occur - on deployment of the application or some piece of code in your application that you might think of the culprit of the exception?

Comment: Yes, post the code that leads to this exception

Comment: i get the above exception when i hit on login button.

Comment: hope its due to above class

Answer (score 0):

1. write a **(j)unit test** for it, e.g. just loading this class via some (maybe self-injected `EntityManager`)
2. **comment out critical parts** that could lead to this, e.g. any entity reference:

   ```
   //@ManyToOne
   //@JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_ID", unique=false, nullable=true, insertable=true, 
   //            updatable=true)
   //private Client client;
   ```

   - and dependent methods inside
3. **run the simple JPA bean, which should likely be fine**
4. now check your **'Client' class, that it does not reference any other entity** and **comment in the above with the most basic settings**, e.g.

   ```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_ID")
   private Client client;
   ```
5. now you **should get closer to the declarations that cause the trouble**

You should **also enable hibernate sql logging and parameter logging** to see whats going on underneath.

**I got a the same error** on a similar setup and it was **caused by a wrong modeling/fiddling with the annotations and relationships** where this source **helped me out: http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/associations/many-to-one.php**